# Modifying a collection makes the entity dirty

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity defined as follows

```
@Entity(name = "Report")
@Table(name = "REPORTS")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true, dynamicUpdate = true, selectBeforeUpdate = true)
public class Report implements java.io.Serializable        {

    /* other fields, getters and setters*/
    @Column(name = "UPD_TIMESTAMP")
    @Version
    private Long updTimestamp;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "report", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ReportItem> reportItems = new ArrayList<ReportItem>();

    public Collection<ReportItem> getReportItems() {
       return reportItems;
    }

    public void setReportItems(Collection<ReportItems> reportItems) {
       this.reportItems = reportItems;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I modify something in reportItems, the Report entity becomes dirty and there is always an update that increments the version field only.

I know abut @OptimisticLock(excluded=true), but i'm stuck to Hibernate 3.2.0 GA and this annotation isn't available. **Is there any workaround to this feature that I can use with Hibernate 3.20 GA**?

Comment: Try removing object from the the context?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by 'dirty' but if the objects become out of sync you cannot blame JPA for this. The application is responsible for keeping sync.

Comment: @siebz0r I mean that even though only items from reportItems collection modify, hibernate think the Report entity is modified and makes an update. But the update only modifies the version field.

Comment: Ah like that. If I am correct you are merging/updating the Report entity. This leaves you with 2 options: 1. Merge/update the ReportItem in stead of the Report entity. 2. Make the collection cascading.

Comment: @siebz0r The problem is that I have to call update on Report entity, because I don't know if it's changed or not. I was hoping that by using SelectBeforeUpdate hibernate will detect if anything changed and update only when needed.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how is `ReportItem` annotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the inverse keyword, maybe this can provide a solution. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-cascade-and-inverse/) it is explained.

Edit: Turns out this is expected behavior. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974240)

Comment: Thanks, @siebz0r! I don't have any cascade defined for the relation between `Report` and `ReportItem` and we have just updated to  Hibernate 3.6 and everything works fine with `@OptimisticLock(excluded=true)` annotation, so I haven't got time to test your solution. But it seems like what I was looking for so I'll accept your answer.