# Hibernate JPA: Update query ( only updating version ) is getting fired even if its not changed at all

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Suppose, we have a User ; one user can have multiple Childs.

Now, when I am inserting a child; I call `user.addChild()` so that user object sitting in JVM is updated .. though actually nothing changes on database record of User as it is OneToMany.

When I am checking SQL; along with insert into child; an additional query is getting fired :

```
update User set version=? where id=? and version=?
```

Any ideas why ? and how to fix this

Comment: which version of Hibernate you are using? I remembered I have seen such behavior before, and it is fixed in a later version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It behaves as specified, if this is owning side of bidirectional relationship. By default unidirectional one-to-many uses join-table, and also then version should be updated. In specification this is told with following words:

> All non-relationship fields and properties and all relationships
>   owned by the entity are included in version checks.
>   ...
>   This includes owned relationships maintained in join tables.